# Ошибка в консоле на запрос google-maps-api

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api

Добрый день! 
На сайт необходимо вставить гугл карту с месторасположением объекта, есть ключ - написан запрос, но при загрузке страницы выбивает в консоли ошибку

```
GET file://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCoqanmncCVy7jVfMrfC64FsxXGdq2yvas&callback=initMap net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

С чем связана данная ситуация и как найти решение данного вопроса? 
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GET file://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCoqanmncCVy7jVfMrfC64FsxXGdq2yvas&callback=initMap net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Данное сообщение говорит о том, что идёт обращение к файлу `file://` по такому-то адресу, где никакого файла нет `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`.

Как это исправить? Заменить в коде `file://` на `https://`.

Comment: Если ответ исправил ошибку, указанную в вопросе, пометьте его как верный.